# Patching the `__call__()` method of a child class from a parent class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have the following lines of code in Python:

```py
from functools import partial 

class DummyClass:
    def load_values(self, prompt, num_inference_steps):
        self = partial(self, prompt=prompt, num_inference_steps=num_inference_steps)

class AnotherDummyClass(DummyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_val = 5

    def __call__(self, prompt=None, num_inference_steps=10):
        if prompt is None:
            raise ValueError("prompt cannot be None.")
        return f"Called with {prompt} and {num_inference_steps}"
```

I am testing this with:

```py
some_class = AnotherDummyClass()
some_class.load_values(prompt="Sayak", num_inference_steps=25)
some_class()
```

As one can see the `load_values()` function explicitly patches the call arguments of the child class. But even then, when I call `some_class()` it leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: prompt cannot be None.
```

How can I remedy this?

If I do the patching outside the scope of the parent class i.e.,

```py
from functools import partial 

some_class = AnotherDummyClass()
some_class = partial(some_class, prompt="hey", num_inference_steps=20)
some_class()
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Note that what you call "patching" is just creating a new [partial object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) and assigning it to the same variable the instance was initially stored in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is just a local variable; while you can reassign to it, such an assignment won't change the object `self` originally points to.

To "save" the arguments, assign them to some (private) attributes, then use them as needed:

```py
class DummyClass:

  # Default values (class level).
  _prompt = None
  _num_inference_steps = None

  # Can also be set instance-level in __init__. Either this or that.
  def __init__(self):
    self._prompt = None
    self._num_inference_steps = None

  def load_values(self, prompt, num_inference_steps):
    self._prompt = prompt
    self._num_inference_steps = num_inference_steps

class AnotherDummyClass(DummyClass):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()  # Remember to call superclass's __init__ iff there is one.
    self.some_val = 5

  def __call__(self, prompt=None, num_inference_steps=10):
    # If 'prompt' is given, use that. Otherwise, fallback to self._prompt.
    prompt = prompt if prompt is not None else self._prompt

    # This one has function-level default value,
    # so this might not be what you want.
    # Modify it as needed.
    num_inference_steps = \
      self._num_inference_steps \
      if self._num_inference_steps is not None else \
      num_inference_steps

    if prompt is None:
      raise ValueError("prompt cannot be None.")
        
    return f"Called with {prompt} and {num_inference_steps}"
```

Personally speaking, I think it's bad design to have such a `.load_values()` method. The user can [import `partial` themself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) should they need it.

Comment: Good answer. You could have also just used `arg or var` instead of `arg if not arg is None else var`

Comment: @OysterShucker `prompt` can be falsy, if anything.

Comment: That's actually what I meant. Obviously doing that with ints is a bad idea. Unless the int should never be 0.

Comment: The example given by OP is somewhat contrived; I'm playing safe here.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are attempting to patch an instance of a sub-class from the parent class because either you don't want to have to write boilerplate code that sets/reads default values in every sub-class, or you are expecting others to use your class as a base class and you want to standardize the usage of instances of any sub-class (code you do not own) from code that you do own.

So if the intention is to customize a sub-class without actually modifying the code of the sub-class, you can do so in the [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) class method, where you would replace the `__call__` method of the sub-subclass with a wrapper method that loads the default values for the instance if `load_values` has been called for the instance before. Default values for an instance be stored in a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` to free up memory once the instance is gone. And the `__call__` method of the base class would be better defined as an abstract method to ensure legitimacy of references to `cls.__call__` in the `__init_subclass__` method:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class DummyClass(ABC):
    _default = object()
    _defaults = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def load_values(self, prompt, num_inference_steps):
        self._defaults[self] = {
           'prompt': prompt,
           'num_inference_steps': num_inference_steps
        }

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls._subclass_call = cls.__call__
        cls.__call__ = cls._call

    def _call(self, prompt=_default, num_inference_steps=_default):
        kwargs = self._defaults.get(self, {})
        if prompt is not self._default:
            kwargs['prompt'] = prompt
        if num_inference_steps is not self._default:
            kwargs['num_inference_steps'] = num_inference_steps
        return self._subclass_call(**kwargs)

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, prompt=_default, num_inference_steps=_default):
        ...
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/1cqNg3